# Open infoWindows from an external link outside of the google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working with the Google Maps API to create a property map. I have it controlled through a Custom Post type which brings in the markers onto the map with infoWindows which open when they're clicked.

I now need to implement some kind of way to list the properties (eventually into a slider) beneath the map so that when the property is clicked outside of the map the map pans to the marker and opens the infoWindow.

At the moment I can't get it to work at all - I'm not a very strong javascript coder so any help would be much appreciated.

I have a list of the post type entries below the map at the moment but no way of linking them..

Here's a snippet of the code so far for the map..

```
     /* MARKER 1 */

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var image = 'http://www.masonyoung.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/mason-new.png';
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    ({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map,
        icon: image
    });



    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });





        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

            if($('.gm-style-iw').length) {
                $('.gm-style-iw').parent().hide();
            }


            infowindow.open( map, marker );


        });



            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            });




    }






}
```

And this is the code I have so far for the list of properties beneath the map..

```
    <?php 
$maps = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );?>

<?php foreach($maps as $map): ?>
    <?php
     $location = get_field('location',$map->ID);
     $price = get_field('price',$map->ID);
     $squareft = get_field('sq_ft_total',$map->ID);
     $buylet = get_field('to_buy_or_to_let',$map2->ID);
     $link = the_permalink($map->ID);

?>


<div id="map_list">

       <ul id="map-locations">

            <li data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">
                <h3><a href="<?php echo post_permalink( $map ); ?>"><?php echo $location['address']; ?></a></h3>
            </li>

        </ul>


     </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You should reduce your code to a minimal version that shows your issue.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the tip, I'm new to all this and I wasn't sure which bit was relevant, I'll make sure I do that next time. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add each marker to a markers array. Then create a link for each marker which contains a reference to the markers index of your marker, this way you can trigger a click event on the marker itself when clicking your external link.

```js
function initMap() {

  var markers = new Array();

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1)
  };

  var locations = [
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 'Marker 1', 'Infowindow content for Marker 1'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 1), 'Marker 2', 'Infowindow content for Marker 2'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(0, 2), 'Marker 3', 'Infowindow content for Marker 3'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 0), 'Marker 4', 'Infowindow content for Marker 4'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1), 'Marker 5', 'Infowindow content for Marker 5'],
    [new google.maps.LatLng(1, 2), 'Marker 6', 'Infowindow content for Marker 6']
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    // Append a link to the markers DIV for each marker
    $('#markers').append('<a class="marker-link" data-markerid="' + i + '" href="#">' + locations[i][1] + '</a> ');

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locations[i][0],
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][1],
    });

    // Register a click event listener on the marker to display the corresponding infowindow content
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }

    })(marker, i));

    // Add marker to markers array
    markers.push(marker);
  }

  // Trigger a click event on each marker when the corresponding marker link is clicked
  $('.marker-link').on('click', function() {

    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[$(this).data('markerid')], 'click');
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="markers"></div>

<!-- 
  The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
  document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
  and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
  with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
  -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" defer></script>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/8gjt0y6p/)</kbd>