# Adding links to Google Maps Markers outside of the map using options in a select dropdown

Tags: jquery, google-maps, infowindow, eventtrigger

I have a Google Map with Various locations and I want to be able to goto and open the Info Window when a link - outside of the map is clicked.

Below is the relevant bits of the working code, but I want to put the links into a select drop down rather than just text links in a div

```
  $('#markers').append('<a class="marker-link" data-markerid="' + i + '" href="#">' + locations[i][1] + '</a> ');

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {

  $('.marker-link').on('click', function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[$(this).data('markerid')], 'click');
  });
```

BTW there is the following div in the HTML

```
  <div id="markers"></div>
```

To try and get it to work as a drop down I have changed this line

```
  $('#markers').append('<a class="marker-link" data-markerid="' + i + '" href="#">' + locations[i][1] + '</a> ');
```

to

```
  $('#dropdown').append('<option data-markerid="' + i + '">' + locations[i][1] + '</option>');
```

and then added this into the HTML

```
  <select id="dropdown"></select>
```

I then do get a drop down with all the various titles and each option has

```
  data-markerid="0"
  data-markerid="1"
```

and I also added

```
  $( "#dropdown" ).change(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[$(this).data('markerid')], 'click');
  });
```

But when I select an item from the drop down it does not go to and show the relevant InfoWindow

Comment: I suspect you want the `marker` click event to fire on the `<select>` change event: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open infoWindows from an external link outside of the google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351008/open-infowindows-from-an-external-link-outside-of-the-google-map)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up doing this in a different way - but it achieves the same result - a Google maps with various locations and a drop down menu outside of the map that can be used to navigate to each location and display the InfoWindow

```
  var map;
  var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var gmarkers = [];
  var side_bar_html = "";

  function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        ...options...
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var markers = [
        ['Location 1', 0, 0, 'Description 1'],
        ['Location 2', 0, 1, 'Description 2'],
        ['Location 3', 1, 0, 'Description 3'],
        ...etc...
      ];

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        marker = addMarker(i);
  }

  // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div

  document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = "<select onchange='myclick(this.value);'>"+side_bar_html+"</select>";

  function addMarker(i) {
        var draftMarker = markers[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(draftMarker[1], draftMarker[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: draftMarker[0]
        });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        info.setContent(draftMarker[3]);
        info.open(map, marker);
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);

  side_bar_html += '<option value=' + (gmarkers.length-1) + '>' + draftMarker[0] + '<\/option>';
    return marker;
    }
  }

  // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window

  function myclick(i) {

  map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And then this added to the HTML

```
  <div id="side_bar"></div>
```